# html form populate pdf text field using javascript and offline solution

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pdf, offline

I have a static HTML application with simple HTML form at the first page (name /address/ phone number /mail) saved with cookies using Javascript

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return storeValues(this);">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Field 1</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" size="32" name="**field1**" value="">
        </span>
        <label>Field 2</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" size="32" name="**field2**" value="">
        </span>
        <label>Field 3</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" size="32" name="**field3**" value="">
        </span>
        <label>Field 4</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" size="32" name="**field4**" value="">
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" value="Valider">
            <input type="button" onclick="clearCookies();" value="Effacer ">
        </span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

There is around 100 static HTML pages connected to this first page where there is around 10 PDF files on different page to download with the same preform text field **(field1,field2, field3, field4).**

When viewer want download this PDF file, the 4 text fields need to get the correct info filled prevously in HTML form.

I have no idea if I could do that using **javascript, offline and without a server and without opening the PDF**.

**The PDF file needs to be unmodified after the download.**

The final HTML app will be also be compiled as an EXE application. (This HTML app is a jQuery area link based with JPEG background.)

There are several solutions on the internet using different SDKs: PDFKit, Easy PDF etc., but I need to get this working offline and if possible using Javascript, because I understand it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla developers are currently working on a PDF reader using HTML 5 and Javascript. Would be interesting if you take a look at the project called [pdf-js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) on the blog of [andreas gal](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/).

Comment: Thanks for the link but looking for a simple way to populate simple html form to pdf text field true javascript or php script and this for an offine html application...Not sure thsi reader could edit the pdf text field

Comment: Unfortunally pdf-js doesn't support images element in IE (my application use IE engine Thanks